# Error de instalación de interfaz SQL en JupiterLab

Tags: sql, jupyter

He estado tratando de instalar una extensión de interfaz de SQL a JupyterLab, y en el proceso, en la consola, se me pide instalar Nodejs, el cual ya he instalado (descargué el instalador desde su misma página), pero aún así no puedo continuar con la instalación.

Me gustaría saber si a alguien le ha pasado esto, o en su defecto, si hay otra manera de trabajar con SQL en JupyterLab.

Comment: Hola Allan, coloca más información sobre el problema, por ejemplo qué error en específico indica el programa. Alguna captura de lo que sucede, etc. Saludos!.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Lo intenté hoy con los mismo comandos para enviar capturas y funcionó.. aquí el tutorial que estuve usando (punto 2).

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/sql-interface-within-jupyterlab

conda install -c conda-forge nodejs

Originalmente me arrojaba error de origen de la web de nodejs al correr ese código. Y no me dejaba seguir con la instalación. 

Gracias de todos modos!! Saludos